# A Secret Riddle

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I can be many colors.
>   Or just red, maybe brown.
>
> I'll tell you where things went wrong,
>   Unless I'm out on the town.
>
> I can be assembled, broken
>   Or even on fire!
>
> You could find me in a d-ring
>   Or policing new hires.
>
> At the bar, you can read me.
>   And monkeys know me well indeed!

What am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it

> Code?

I can be many colors.
Or just red, maybe brown.

> Colour code, Code red and Code brown

I'll tell you where things went wrong,
Unless I'm out on the town.

> Error code and Post code

I can be assembled, broken
Or even on fire!

> You can break a code, (Thanks Rubio!) an assembly code and (Thanks @Sconibulus) Fire Code

You could find me in a d-ring
Or policing new hires.

> A (Thanks @Deusovi) decoding ring and (Thanks @Rubio) code of conduct

At the bar, you can read me.
And monkeys know me well indeed!

> A bar-code and (Thanks @Sconibulus) Code Monkey

And, of course, the title: 'A secret riddle'

> Talking in code